# ExcelCreator need 1.4 GB RAM when open 14MB Excel file

Tags: excel, vb.net, memory

I am using the ExcelCreator library to process a 14MB Excel file. However, it takes up 1.4GB of RAM when opening it.

[image]

How to reduce memory?
When opening the file with Microsoft Excel, it only takes up 300MB of RAM

```
public void open(string filepath)
        {
            creator = new Creator();
            creator.OpenBookEx(filepath, "", ref info);
        }
```

Comment: I doubt there's anything you can do as a client of ExcelCreator; the tooling comes with its footprint. Or is part of that footprint your own code?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Sorry, actually I couldn't find any documentation other than the library's homepage : http://aws.adv.co.jp/demo/excelcreator10/Page/SetValue.aspx.  Besides, I also see a document of an older version : https://origin2.cdn.componentsource.com/sites/default/files/resources/advance-software/533476/manual_excelcreator5.pdf